# How to make WebFilter work in a non-WebFlux/non-reactive Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, filter, spring-webflux

I'm trying to solve this: [How to rewrite URLs with Spring (Boot) via REST Controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63707296/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-spring-boot-via-rest-controllers/63708072)
by creating some kind of "filter" which would be applied to every incoming HTTP request.

The matter is covered by some answers like for this question: [Spring Boot Adding Http Request Interceptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082981/spring-boot-adding-http-request-interceptors)
but interface `HandlerInterceptor` deals with javax' `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` which are not as practical as the new class introduced by Spring i.e. the `ServerWebExchange` (see the use of `setLocation()` in the code below) which appears in an interface whose name sounds promising, `org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter`:

So I ended with something like:

```
@Component
public class LegacyRestRedirectWebFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        URI origin = exchange.getRequest().getURI();
        String path = origin.getPath();
        if (path.startsWith("/api/")) {
            ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
            response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
            URI location = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(origin).replacePath(path.replaceFirst("/api/", "/rest/")).build().toUri();
            response.getHeaders().setLocation(location);
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }

}
```

...in the same way people are doing something similar like:

- [Spring WebFlux add WebFIlter to match specific paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53080263/spring-webflux-add-webfilter-to-match-specific-paths)
- [WebFilter in WebFlux application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920851/webfilter-in-webflux-application)

Alas, my filter is never called!!!

The thing is: I am not in a "WebFlux" context (on the contrary to the questions above) because:

1. I don't need to, and
2. I tried and got the following problems:

- [Reactive Webfilter is not working when we have spring-boot-starter-web dependency in classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59668246/reactive-webfilter-is-not-working-when-we-have-spring-boot-starter-web-dependenc) (but no definitive answer); marked duplicate of:
  [Don't spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-webflux work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51377675/does-not-the-spring-boot-starter-web-and-spring-boot-starter-webflux-work-togeth)
- [Spring WebFlux with traditional Web Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53847627/spring-webflux-with-traditional-web-security) (I have the "traditional" `spring-boot-starter-security` dependency in my `pom.xml` plus a `@Configuration` class extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` - but not willing to migrate it to... what by the way?)

Also I don't understand why would I need to be in a WebFlux context, because `org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter` neither deals with `reactive` nor `Webflux`, right? ..or does it? This is not very clear in the Javadoc.

Comment: your application is either a web application, or a webflux application. It cant be both, webfilter is part of webflux, so it will be loaded and used if your application is a webflux application. If you have both web and webflux on your classpath spring boot will per default start as a web application and you should be using a `Filter` https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter without seing your pom.xml/gradle its hard know what type of application you have.

Comment: how can WebFilter be part of "WebFlux" as it's located in `spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar`?!

Comment: btw, as you requested the pom.xml on another question of mine, I posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63737318/why-does-spring-boot-starter-webflux-import-spring-web

Comment: ...also thanks for pointing me towards this (simple) `Filter` but after a quick search (albeit the Baeldung not specifying which Filter it is...) I found out this is the `javax.servlet.Filter` and as I said above, I'll try to avoid working with this as it's pure "javax" code and it deals with (Http)ServletRequest/(Http)ServletResponse, [see the casts in `RequestResponseLoggingFilter`].

Comment: Well since i havn't seen your pom.xml (until now) many ppl add webflux to their spring-web application to use only the `WebClient`. Hence the default, you on the other hand, want to be using `WebFilter` since you want to build a webflux application. And your problem is that you are pulling in things that does not support webflux (springfox v2.9.2) so springfox is probably forcing your app to start as a web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, I didn't find a way to make `WebFilter` work in a non-WebFlux context, but I could successfully implement such a filter, which both implements `javax.servlet.Filter` (non-reactive) AND `org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter` (reactive).

Here is my answer to the other related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63780659/666414